# Git: Add non-default branch from another repo as new branch

Tags: git, github

I like to think that this should be simple but have been unable to find the answer, I hope someone smarter than me can help me with this.

How can I add a new branch locally from a non-default branch on another repo?

The code base is the same but the repos are separate. I want to take a branch from a remote repo and have it as a new branch on my local repo but not the default branch locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must add the other repo as a remote :

```
git remote add {{ set a name for the remote }} {{ repo url }}
```

Then you fetch the objects from that repository with :

```
git fetch {{ name for the remote }}
```

Finally you can check out the branch locally with :

```
git checkout -b {{ name for local branch }} remotes/{{ name of remote }}/{{ name of remote branch }}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be along the lines of

```
git remote add new_repo http://your.site/repo.git
git fetch new_repo
git checkout new_repo/that_branch
```

You can read about remotes in the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)